# After WordPress website migration fonts don't load anymore

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts, migration

After migrating my website from a temporary URL to the live site, I cannot seem to understand why the fonts are not rendering and are instead returning a 404 error in the console.

The live site is here: http://canadatkd.com

The temporary site is here: http://d09.cdb.myftpupload.com

I'm seeing the following error below on the live site:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

But I've checked the files and they are indeed there in the FTP but on the live site it's showing me that the files are non-existent.

Can anyone please let me know why this is occurring?

Thank you!

Comment: This is now fixed guys! Sorry for the false alarm as it had to do with some corrupt WordPress core files.

Answer (score 0):

The working site has this in the head

```
http://canadatkd.com/wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css?ver=4.2.0
```

The new site does not. Is the font awesome plugin installed and/or not activated?

Comment: The font awesome plugin is installed and activated. It's just returnining a 404 error on the actual font files themselves but I checked the FTP and its showing me all files are there! So strange.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect element on both versions and click on the Sources tab and then drill down into the following directory

wp-content/themes/Avada/assets/fonts/icomoon

You will notice on the new "live site" that the directory sturcture is missing the icomoon direcotry and files. Same goes for the fontawesome-webfont.woof2 etc files.

I'm not sure if you manually installed fontawesome or are trying implement it with a plugin but you need to move those files into the same location as the test server. That's why you're getting a 404.

Comment: That's exactly what I had originally done but the thing is I have the exact same files in the same location as the test server. That's why it's so strange because I'm using the exact same file/folder structure as the test site but even still it's showing me a 404 error. What can possibly be the reason for this?

Comment: According to what is rendering on my screen, those files are not there. Very strange indeed. Are you using any type of caching plugin for WP? Also for what it's worth, 9 out of 10 times that I move a WP site. Even after I change the base URLs manually in the DB I have to go into settings > Permalinks in the back end and change the setting, save it, change it back to page/post name and save it again in order to get the inner pages of the site to render. Otherwise they 404. I've never seen an error like this before but it might be worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

Your web host admin is probably blocking CSS from Nginx loadbalancer on test site or serving via custom port to cache. Somehow thing is not working rightly.

You have no fault. Ask your that test web host's support. It is not possible to fix without root access of the test servers.

Your other server is running Apache. These are test results speaking of the above (output limited) :

```
curl -I http://d09.cdb.myftpupload.com/wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Port: port_10305
X-Cache: uncached
X-Cache-Hit: MISS
X-Backend: all_requests
```

This is production site :

```
curl -I http://canadatkd.com/wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Backend aka test server likely to have this kind of settings for security reason :

```
if (oSession.uriContains(".css")){
oSession.oRequest.FailSession(404, "Blocked", "Fiddler blocked CSS    file");
}
```